# Creating an executable jar with groovy script

Tags: groovy, jar

I have a groovy script `Automate.groovy`. The script does not have a class definition or a main method. I am looking for the simplest way to create a jar containing the script. I tried compiling the groovy script using the following command:

```
groovyc Automate.groovy
```

I also have a Manifest file manifest-addition.txt that specifies the main class

```
Main-Class: Automate
```

And I created the jar using the command:

```
jar cvfm Automate.jar mainfest-addition.txt *.class
```

This gave me a jar with Automate.class and Automate$1.class and a Manifest file with the Main class. But when I tried to run the jar using `java -jar Automate.jar` I always get the error

```
cannot find or load main class Automate.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

There should be a simple way like this to create the jar. I just have this one script file that I want in my jar and I do not want to use maven/ant/gradle to get this job done. Isn't there a simple and straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

The class file has dependencies on Groovy. Using the embeddable jar will fix the problem.

Using Groovy 2.4.5, if I have this script for Automate.groovy

```
println "Hello from Automate.groovy"
```

and use this manifest.txt:

```
Main-class: Automate
Class-path: jar/groovy-all-2.4.5.jar
```

and this simple build script:

```
rm *.class
groovyc Automate.groovy
jar cvfm Automate.jar manifest.txt Automate.class
```

and, in the run directory, I perform this:

```
bash$ mkdir jar
bash$ cp $GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.4.5.jar jar
```

then this works:

```
bash$ java -jar Automate.jar 
Hello from Automate.groovy
```

The solution will be much better if the embeddable jar is included in the Automate.jar itself. An example of that, using Gradle, is [this project](https://github.com/peidevs/WarO_Groovy).

Comment: Why is it a better solution to include the groovy-all jar inside Automate.jar?

Comment: I actually tried including groovy-all jar in classpath using java -cp groovy-all.jar Automate.jar. Even then I got the same error. I actually had a @Grab annotation and that is what was actually causing the problem. When I removed it, it was able to locate the main class

Comment: @Harini to include it with `-classpath` you would need to add it in addition to the jar file, like: `java -cp Automate.jar:groovy-all-2.4.5.jar Automate`

Answer (score -1):

The actual problem was the @Grab Annotation that was there in my script. I created a Gradle project and added a very simple script HelloWorld.groovy with just one println statement but also used a @Grab to just import something. When I built the jar it would not find the main class. When I googled around I found that the @Grab annotation is meant to be used in standalone scripts and not for pre-compiled script. So if you need to have @Grab in your compiled groovy then you need to add an additional ivy dependency or choose not to have the @Grab and use some other way to include dependencies. I removed @Grab from my script and then built it. The jar executed fine then.

Sorry btw for deviating from the fact that I did not want to use Gradle/Maven. I almost spent two days trying all the things that I could find on stackoverflow and google and ended up trying Gradle. I am not sure if this is the only solution to the problem but this worked for me.